# Cant expose a port on the host but exposing on docker works

Tags: linux, networking, debian, docker

I have an AWS instance.
All incoming and out going traffic is allowed on all ports.

I run `python3 -m http.server 8000`
on the host but then I cant access `<hostIP>:8000` from outside the host machine.

Now If I run docker container `docker run -di -p 8000:8000 ubuntu` on the same host.

and inside the docker container I run `python3 -m http.server 8000` I am able to GET `<hostIP>:8000` from outside the host machine.

cant wrap my head around this. Any ideas about what might be happening?

PS: I did a tcpdump and found that the host is receiving the tcp SYN packet but its not responding with a SYNACK.

PPS: `lsof -Pi :8000`

`python3 13376 root    3u  IPv4  71025      0t0  TCP *:8000 (LISTEN)`

Comment: i belive its a binding isse, did you tried `python3 -m http.server 0.0.0.0:8000` i am not having knowledge to python but without seen any `lsof -Pi :8000` output its just a thought about

Comment: @djdomi tried binding to 0.0.0.0. still same issue

Comment: please take care of the second part of my comment. and Remind to update the Question instead adding comments

Comment: @djdomi `python3 13376 root    3u  IPv4  71025      0t0  TCP *:8000 (LISTEN)`

Comment: What is the error message you get when you try to connect to your port?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider No error. Requests just hangs and then timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ufw` service was blocking everything on the system. Docker was configuring `ufw` properly and hence was working out of the box. I stoped `ufw` and everything is working.
Facepalm moment.